# Java parse bytes number over 39.4 GB on a long var bug

Tags: java, math

I have an app that get ftp disk space. so space given by a number that present how many bytes.

the problem is when i got space over 39.4 GB i can just store 39.4*1024*1024*1024 in a long or double var. so if you have 50 GB it just show you 39.4. whats the solution?

Comment: I'm sorry to say, I cannot understand you question. Can you please paste your code, its output, and what you expected its output to be? Thanks

Comment: You must be doing something wrong. In a long you probably can store sizes up to approx 2^33 or  16 billion Gigabytes

Comment: What Ingo said, you should be able to fit the number of bytes in 39.4GB into a 64-bit integer long several hundred million times over...

Comment: You must be doing something wrong, but unless you show code that substantiates your claim, we can't tell you what it is.

Comment: @Ingo Java longs are signed 64-bit, so the limit is 2^63 - 1 (perhaps the 33 in your comment was a typo?). That's about 8 billion gigabytes (actually 1 byte less than 8 exabytes -- or exbibytes if you prefer the weird names).

Comment: @Laurence, longs are 64bit, and so we can represent 2^64 different values (or sizes up to 16 billion GB). Whether we interpret the values as signed or unsigned is another story. But we can do it, even if the java language by default chooses the signed interpretation. When we reach 0x7fffffffffffffff and add 1, we get 0x8000000000000000, and that is perfectly valid. We just must not use print or toString() or such, as this will invariably interpret the number as signed quantity.

Comment: @Ingo Sure, you can store any 64-bit value you want in a long as long as you don't expect the standard library routines to interpret it your way for you. If that's what you really meant then your typo was worse than I originally thought. Instead of "2^33" you should have written 2^64-1.

Comment: @Laurence: I said "2^33 (or approx. 16 billion) Gigabyte". Perhaps I always should set parentheses explicitly. And this number is still correct, give or take one in the exponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if BigInteger class helps you with your problem

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html

EDIT:

Actually as others already mentioned, long value will be able to hold a really big value, it can hold far more than 40gb as a number value

Answer (score 3):

[`long` can store much larger values](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) -- so there must be something specific in your code. I guessed at what your code is doing, see if this looks familiar:

```
class Out {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long l = 40L * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
        double d = 40.0 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
        System.out.println("long l: " + l + " double d: " + d + "\n");
        return;
    }
}

$ vim Out.java ; javac Out.java ; java Out 
long l: 42949672960 double d: 4.294967296E10
```

Note that I had to multiply `40L` rather than just `40` -- if all integers are given as literal integers, without specific `L` `long` annotations, then Java will interpret the entire expression as an `int`. When testing with and without the `L` (and multiplying by just `1024 * 1024 * 102`, building up to confirming my hypothesis), I found the differences entertaining:

```
$ vim Out.java ; javac Out.java ; java Out # with only '40'
long l: -16777216 double d: 4.294967296E10

$ vim Out.java ; javac Out.java ; java Out # with '40L'
long l: 4278190080 double d: 4.294967296E10
```

I hope this helps explain why it is important to specify the types of literal data types in the code.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for storing an amount greater than 39.4 GB:

```
final long kb = 1024L;
final long mb = 1024L*kb;
final long gb = 1024L*mb;
long solution = 42L * gb;  // > 39.4 GB in a long
```

Answer (score 0):

`long` can record 8 Exa-bytes which is 8 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 GB (minus one byte ;)